# Fixed point iteration with While or Do Loop

Tags: homework, iterators, iteration

I need to write a while or do loop to perform the iteration $x_{n+1}=Cos(x_n)$ with initial value $x_0=1$ and stops when the absolute value of the difference between two consecutive iterations is $|x_{n+1}-x_n|<\epsilon$ , where $\epsilon =10^{-16}$. Finally print the final value $x_{n+1}$, displaying 16 decimal digits.

I can define the relevant function and variables, but don't know exactly how to execute the while loop to return me the required solution, here is my code:

```
epsilon = 10^{-6}

h[n] = Cos[n]

h[n + 1] = Cos[h[n]]

h[0] = 1

While[Abs[h[n + 1] - h[n]] < epsilon,
 n = n + 1;
 h[n + 1] = Cos[h[n]];
 Print[h[n]]
 ]
```

I know other programming languages, but working with mathematica and its function layouts is a bit hard until I get used to it. If someone can help me how to set up this function with a while or do loop, and explain me its procedure, I will appreciate their effort and time.

Comment: Study this `x=1;While[Abs[Cos[x]-x]>=epsilon,x=Cos[x]];N[x,16]` and see if it does what you want. Perhaps include a `Print[N[Abs[Cos[x]-x],16]]` inside the the loop so you can watch the convergence until you believe you can trust it.

Comment: Now that fixed point, why not `FixedPoint`?

Comment: I think the definition `h[n] = Cos[n]` isn't what you want; you only want `h[0] = 1` and `h[n + 1] = Cos[h[n]]`. Otherwise, when given, say, `h[3]`, should mathematica produce `Cos[3]` (first definition) or `Cos[h[2]]` (second)? However, the thing is that you don't actually want to use any of these definitions at all! The code inside the while loop is what's setting the value of `h[something]`; it shouldn't be set outside of that context if you're not going to use it, as it might produce weird behavior.

Comment: Also note that defining, say, `h[5] = Cos[h[4]]` stores the value of h[5] as part of its definition for h, while still remembering the prior values. But if you only need the last two values, you can just make a name for the most recent two values, e.g. `h` and `h0`, and have the "time of the while loop" implicitly provide your $n$. You can assign them both at once via `{h,h0} = {Cos[h],h}`. (Note how the value of `h0` is thrown away, as it becomes "too old" to be relevant.) You could also eschew the second variable in favor of just the function applied to `h0`, as suggested in another comment.

Comment: Also note that your condition ini the `While` loop is reversed: as is, it's saying "while the difference is less than epsilon, execute my code". But you want "*until* the difference is less than epsilon"! I.e., `Abs[h-h0] >= epsilon`. Also: you currently have `epsilon = 10^{-6}`. Mathematica generally doesn't accept LaTeX notation; this is saying "10 to the power of the list containing the element -6". You want epsilon = `10^(-6)`!

Comment: Note that as of now, as well, the `Print` statement is inside the loop, so it will priint every value encountered, not just the final one—I'm not sure if that's what you want. Likewise, any complete expression ending a line with no semicolon after it will be shown as output; so you technically don't need `Print` if you don't want! likewise, the variable assignment of `epsilon`, `h[0]`  will be printed in the above code. Finally: to give it with 16 digits, you can use `N[h,16]` as above, or use something like `DecimalForm[h,16]`. hope this was helpful! let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: (Also one last thing: the initial values for h and h0, set outside the While loop, could be either `h0 = 1` and `h = Cos[1]`, or you could go a step "backwards" and note that $cos(0) = 1$, setting `h = 1` and `h0 = 0`!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define any functions. You just need to write a While-loop.

It is tempting to write the While-loop to use system floating-point arithmetic for speed, like so:

```
With[{ϵ = 10.^-16},
  Block[{x = 1., nxt},
    While[True,
      nxt = Cos[x];
      If[Abs[nxt - x] < ϵ, Break[], x = nxt]];
    nxt]]
```

But this doesn't work because system floating-point arithmetic can't maintain 16 digits of precision over the iteration. To avoid this numerics problem, the While-loop can be written to compute with exact numbers.  The final value will be converted to a 16-digit arbitrary precision number.

```
With[{ϵ = 10^-16},
  Block[{x = 1, nxt},
    While[True,
      nxt = Cos[x];
      If[Abs[nxt - x] < ϵ, Break[], x = nxt]];
  N[nxt, 16]]]
```

> 0.7390851332151606

The above can be simplified a little by using an undocumented feature of `Break`. It returns its argument when given one.

```
With[{ϵ = 10^-16},
  Block[{x = 1, nxt},
    While[True,
      nxt = Cos[x];
      If[Abs[nxt - x] < ϵ, Break[N[nxt, 16]], x = nxt]]]]
```

The code editor complains about this use of `Break`, but the evaluator accepts it and it works fine.

I also feel I should point out that it is better Mathematica practice to use `FixedPoint` than to write a While-loop.

```
With[{ϵ = 10^-16},
  N[FixedPoint[Cos, 1, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < ϵ &)], 16]]
```

> 0.7390851332151606